# How to convert a clever require to an import?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

Previously I was using a clever index.js file:

```
var all = { ..... };

module.exports = _.merge(all,
   require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') || {});
```

To import my env settings baed on the NODE_ENV, and where I have files such as:

```
development.js
production.js
shared.js
...
```

And when I did a require() for this index.js file, I recieved the env variables I wanted based on my NODE_ENV setting.

Is there any way to do this with ES6 and import???

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I needed to use a different solution for ES6.  You can do a `declare require(package: string);` which will be bound to the correct method after the translation to normal js for the browser.  Then do a:

```
let foo_package = require('foo');
```

but this seems a bit more difficult.  Instead I created:

```
development.ts
test.ts,
production.ts
```

and

```
import development from 'development';
import test from 'test';
import production from 'production';

export function choose(env: string) {
    switch(env) {
      case 'development':
         return development;
      case 'test'
         return test;
      case 'production':
         return production;
      default:
         throw Error(`choose 'development', 'test', or 'production'!);
     }
 }
```

This worked just as well and didn't need plain js;

Comment: Instead of a `switch` you might want to create a lookup map as `{development, test, production}`

Comment: I use Map<string, string> in many other locations, and I like that there.  What advantage is this over a switch?  Just your thoughts?  I would guess it's about the same amount of code and a bit more memory? But perhaps there is more?

Comment: Much less code and better maintainability are my thoughts :-)